# Error with program that opens file, reads data, and calculates the average

Tags: c#

I was given an assignment in my programming class with a prompt that directly reads,

> "In this exercise exam scores for a class of students is stored in a file. You are to write a program that successfully opens the file, reads in the exam scores, and outputs them on the console."

Every time I run my program an error occurs showing that,

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in GradeCalculator.exe"

The error appears on the code, "gradesArray[i] = gradesArray[gradeData];
                        i++;"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace GradeCalculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\grades.txt";
            int gradeData;
            StreamReader grades = new StreamReader(folder);
            int[] gradesArray = new int[50];
            while (!grades.EndOfStream)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i != 50;)
                {
                    gradeData = int.Parse(grades.ReadLine());

                    gradesArray[i] = gradesArray[gradeData];
                    i++;
                }
            }

            Program calc = new Program();

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
            {
                int average = calc.averageArr(gradesArray);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", average);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public int averageArr(int[] arr)
        {
            int avg = 0;
            int numGrades = 0;
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                do
                {
                    sum += arr[i];
                } while (arr[i] != 0);
            }
            avg = sum / numGrades;
            return avg;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Data from file:
88
90
78
65
50
83
75
23
60
94

**EDITED NEW CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace GradeCalculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\grades.txt";
            int gradeData;
            StreamReader grades = new StreamReader(folder);
            int[] gradesArray = new int[50];
            do
            {
                gradeData = int.Parse(grades.ReadLine());
                for (int i = 0; i != gradesArray.Length;)
                {
                    gradesArray[i] = gradeData;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            while (!grades.EndOfStream);

            Program calc = new Program();

            int average = calc.averageArr(gradesArray);

             Console.WriteLine("{0}", average);
             Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public int averageArr(int[] arr)
        {
            int avg = 0;
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i != arr.Length; )
            {
                sum += arr[i];
                i++;
            }

            avg = sum / arr.Length;
            return avg;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unless you show how your data appear in the file, it is hard to suggest anything.

Comment: My hunch is  `gradesArray[gradeData];` causing the problem, when any value in file is `>= 50`

Comment: is data in single line or multiple lines?

Comment: @HariPrasad Multiple lines

Comment: gradeData = int.Parse(grades.ReadLine());
maybe at this line you are getting value more or equal than 50?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lot of redundant code, you simply could use `Linq` and get an array of `int`.

```
var intArray = File.ReadAllLines("filepath")
                   // Remove below line if you have only 1 number in each line, else specify delimiter and keep it.
                   .SelectMany(s=>s.Split(' '))                        
                   .Select(int.Parse);
```

Once you get the array, Array has function which returns `Average`

```
var average = intArray.Average();
```

**Update:**

Since you want to write function that calculates average, you could do this. Please note I modified few variable types to `Decimal` to avoid `int`division.

```
public decimal averageArr(int[] arr)
{
    decimal avg = 0;
    int numGrades = 0;
    decimal sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    avg = sum / arr.Length;
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my teacher requires me to use a method that calculates the average.

Comment: Ohh.. ok, in that case you can use your function that calculates average, but be cautious in performing `int` division.

Comment: Now it is giving me an error stating, "Program.averageArr(int[]) cannot be accessed with an instance reference"                                                                 int average = calc.averageArr(gradesArray);

Comment: remove `static` in the method defintion.

Comment: I still have the same error shown in my new code. Is there anything else that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Method returns `decimal` value, but in your calling code you are using `int`.   use this `decimal average = calc.averageArr(gradesArray); `.

Comment: Thank you for the help but it was the problem shown earlier. I have posted my new code yet "gradesArray[i] = gradesArray[gradeData];" still shows the same error.

Comment: Tried giving you lot and the best solutions, not sure what exactly you are looking for. I'm tired :-).

Comment: My original error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in GradeCalculator.exe" still has not changed.

Comment: Change this line `gradesArray[i] = gradesArray[gradeData];` to `gradesArray[i] = gradeData;`, it should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help! My math is now wrong for it is giving me 1.88 but I am pretty sure I will be able to figure it out somehow.